# How to Improve number of fetch MQ message rate IBM MQ .NET consumer application

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, mq

```
 public string GetMessage()
    {
        MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage()
        {
            Version = MQC.MQMD_VERSION_2
        };

        this.queue.Get(retrievedMessage, getMessageOptions);
        
        if (retrievedMessage.DataLength == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var message = retrievedMessage.ReadString(retrievedMessage.DataLength);
        return message;
    }

 this.getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT
                | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                | MQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG,
            // it is adviced not to use MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT
           WaitInterval = 10000, 
           MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE
        };

 public void Connect()
    {
        this.queueManager = new MQQueueManager(Configuration.ManagerName, Configuration.ToMqHashTable());
        // If Browse is ever needed: MQC.MQOO_BROWSE
        this.queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(this.Configuration.QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE);
    }
```

Above code snippet took form my **MqClient** class, after connected to the MQ successfully I can fetch the messages from MQ using **GetMessage()**  sample code shown in below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("SATS DataFeeder POC");
        dataBuffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
        var timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        int messageCount = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsConnected)
                    InitializeClient();

                var data = client.GetMessage();
                dataBuffer.Post(data);
                //count = client.CountMessagesInQueue();
                messageCount += 1;
                Console.WriteLine($"Queue count : {messageCount}");

                if (messageCount == 100)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    var totalSeconds = timer.Elapsed.Seconds;
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Consumption Rate = Total Time taken to consume 100 messages  = " + 100 / totalSeconds + " messages/second");
                }
            }
            catch (MQException exc) when (exc.ReasonCode == (int)MQExceptionReasonCodes.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
            catch (MQException exc) when (exc.ReasonCode == (int)MQExceptionReasonCodes.MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
            catch (MQException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
        }
    }
```

currently it reads **100 messages in 14 seconds** and **8 messages per second**. This speed is not enough since there are many messages keep adding to the queue in peak times and it raise many **MQ** **threshold exceed alerts**. I want a better solution to handle consume speed of my sample application in order to avoid alerts and MQ queue depth reach to **30000** in peak time. the application is using **.NET core 3.1 targeted framework** and IBM nugget package **IBMMQDotnetClient 9.2.5**. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: I see that your program reports the time it took once it managed to read 100 messages. Were there 100 messages present on the queue before it started, or does the time it is measuring include wait for the messages to arrive on the queue. Since your time is so rubbish, I am suspecting the latter.

Comment: P.S. MQGMO_CONVERT is ALWAYS recommended.

Comment: @MoragHughson I added in production it runs without if (messageCount == 100)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    var totalSeconds = timer.Elapsed.Seconds;
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Consumption Rate = Total Time taken to consume 100 messages  = " + 100 / totalSeconds + " messages/second");
                } i added this part only testing purposes to measure time for read first 100 messages in a second.

Comment: That is interesting, but doesn't answer my question. How much of the measured time is spent waiting for messages because the queue is empty?

Comment: @MoragHughson It present 100+ messages before start the queue read. if queue is empty it waits 10 seconds. But i made a mistake of timer start location before timer start before MQ connection create so i corrected it not start the timer after the connection open 100 messages will read in 7seconds and 1000 messages reads in 64 seconds, are there any further optimization ? I used MQGMO_CONVERT as you mentioned

Comment: What are you doing for each message? I see a line that shows a "Post" of the message - what is this doing? How much time in your 7 seconds is spent in there? Have you updated your question to show your current application btw?

Comment: What are you doing for each message? In Production application after post messages into a buffer block , Data processor will take them and process messages and save results into a database. How much time in your 7 seconds is spent in there? 7 seconds only spent reading part as i mentioned above code snippet is from reading MQ messages from queue which we used in the production application. yes i updated the changes in the real application, but it is need more optimization in order to production ready.  I decided to use 3 instances of consumers to queue (3 instance of above code) to read faster

Comment: but i am afraid it may change the order of process messages but it is fast enough to reduce the queue depth in peak times. so i am thinking to put all 3 instances post messages into a one common buffer block and take messages from there to process and save into a database.

Comment: Are you doing MQCONNect once - or once per message? Will your Public connect do a disconnect on exit ? so causing a connect for every message?

Comment: @colin paice it only once connect to the queue , i do have disconnect when there is a exception occurs client will disconnect and reconnect. also when mqclient dispose  disconnect will happen. causing a connect for every message ? no only one time

Comment: @MoragHughson i have a update for you . thanks

Comment: Could you explain, by updating your question PLEASE, what the Post you do during the measure time is, and how long it takes.